# delphi 7 TRichtEdit

Tags: delphi

I am having .rtf extension file that's contents in tabular format, Now I want to import this .rtf file in TRichEdit control (only contents in formatted order not table grid-line), means want to hide gridlines after importing.

pls tell me solution for Delphi7

Thnks Shashi Jaiswal

Comment: I think you'll need some 3rd party tool to process the RTF. Personally, I would use Office automation and get Word to do it, but that may not be a viable solution for you. We don't have a lot of information to go on yet.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591004/loading-rtf-file-having-table-in-trichedit-without-table-borders

Answer (score 1):

You may want to post on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) instead.

Also, I think you want to "import to TRichEdit", not "export".

And finally, if you load the file in a *TMemoryStream*, you could do something like `RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromStream(theStream)` (where "RichEdit1" is the name of the TRichEdit and theStream is the TMemoryStream) but I haven't tested it, delphi 7 fails to work on my new computer :(

Comment: ya definatelly want to "import to TRichEdit", and i am using same line to read RTF file but table structure also import with contents.